# Releasing items in the hold of a ship makes it easier to rock a ship?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, buoyancy, coupled-oscillators

There's a scene in the movie Pirates of the Caribbean III (At World's End) wherein the characters are trying to flip their pirate ship upside down as it floats in the water. To do this, they try to rock the boat to a really large amplitude, by running from one side of the deck to the other together, thereby trying some kind of forced oscillation. From what I've experienced on boats, it is certainly possible to force the rocking of the boat in this manner. You can view the relevant 3-minute long section of the movie on YouTube [here](https://youtu.be/sNj8mJq65i4).

At one point, they choose to release the heavy items in the hold of the ship to let them slide. I don't understand how this would help force the oscillations and increase the amplitude, and I was hoping that someone could explain this. Alternatively, if releasing the items in the hold of the ship does not help force larger amplitudes and the movie's physics is incorrect, I would like to know what effect they do have when the people are running around on top are trying to force oscillations. Do they do nothing? Does some phase difference emerge and cause them to oppose the forcing attempted by the people on the deck? Ideally, I'm hoping an answer could somehow create a simplified coupled oscillator system in terms of familiar laboratory springs, masses, and pendulums, which serves as an analogy for this case.

So far, while coming up with an analogy, I've tried considering a pendulum bob filled with spherical balls inside, but I can't think of how the forcing used by the people on the ship could be simulated in this model.